# Dynamic Custom Post Type Plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development

I am trying to build my own lightweight plugin that will register Custom Post Types. The problem I am having is that I can create a post type but I can't figure out how to save the previous post type and then create another one with each new entry.

```
function create_custom_post_type() {

if (isset($_POST['tme_post_type_singular'])) {
    update_option('tme_post_type_singular', $_POST['tme_post_type_singular']);
    $value = $_POST['tme_post_type_singular'];
} 

$value = get_option('tme_post_type_singular', '');

if (isset($value)) {

    $custom_posts = array(
        "slug" => $value,
        "name" => $value . 's',
        "singular_name" => $value,
        "is_public" => true,
        "has_archive" => false,
    );

    register_post_type( $value,
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( $custom_posts['name'] ),
                'singular_name' => __( $custom_posts['singular_name'] )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );


}

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_post_type' );
```

How can change this code to allow me to create more than one post type every time I input new entries?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the CPT in the options table, try using `register_post_type` immediately when you submit the form, then display a success confirmation plus the empty form again. This will have two benefits - one being you're not bloating the options table, the other being that you'll immediately register the CPT and be able to submit the form with the next CPT immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, when you use the register_post_type function when I submit the form. Should I use $_POST rather than get_option(); ? @WebElaine

Comment: Yes, exactly. Use the `$_POST`ed variables from your form and immediately create the CPT, rather than storing anything in the database. (You would want some data validation - check if all the required POST variables are set and if not, display an error message and the form with what you've filled out so far - but if all required info is there create the CPT immediately without storing the data, and display the form again so you can create as many as you need.)

Comment: You are right that I can create a CPT, but when I want to create another CPT it just replaces the previous CPT rather than creating an additional CPT. Any Suggestions? @WebElaine